# Create sub column in csv based on field values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe from csv which has values like this

```
position, location
1,0,1, 1.2,2.2
```

based on comma separated values I want to create sub columns like shown in the diagram. No of comma separated will remain same for all. For e.g. If one location value has 2 fields then all of them will have 2 fields. So I need to separate these values by comma and create sub columns based on that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on each of the column and create a new dataframe from each of this column, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) along `axis=1` and with optional parameter `keys` to concat the dataframes creating a `MultiIndex` columns.

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(df[c].astype(str).str.split(',').tolist())
                   .rename(lambda x: f'Field{x + 1}', axis=1) for c in df.columns]      
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
```

Result:

```
    position               location       
    Field1 Field2 Field3   Field1 Field2
0        1      0      1      1.2    2.2
```

Comment: I am getting position 3 times and location 2 times in the header part. They are somehow repeated for each sub-column when I export to csv.

Comment: Its just representation in `csv` file.

Comment: Shubham Sharma need some help in simplifying this function. Can we have a chat?

Comment: @user1298426 Sure. Join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219748/ds9)

Comment: How did you create a chat room? Couldn't find a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest way to achieve this is to use a `dict` comprehension from the dictionary produced by `to_dict(orient="list")`

This could be extended to deal with multiple *before* rows

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""position  location

1,0,1   ,1.2,2.2"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

d = df.to_dict(orient="list")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({tuple([k, f"field{e+1}"]):[i] 
 for k in d.keys() 
 for e,i in enumerate(d[k][0].strip(",").split(","))})
```

**output**

```
position               location       
  field1 field2 field3   field1 field2
       1      0      1      1.2    2.2
```

Comment: getting this exception AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'.